# OutOfMemory Exception while using ImageTools for Windows Phone

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, out-of-memory

I am trying to play Gifs in my Windows Phone 8 Silverlight app. For this I am using [Imagetools](https://imagetools.codeplex.com/). It is working perfectly except sometimes when I am getting `OutOfMemoryException`. I am using a Nokia Lumia 1020 ( 2 GB RAM, memory usage limit 780 MB ) for testing purposes.

I have a SilverLight `ListBox` and have multiple templates in it. Two of which are -

```
<local:ModuleTemplateSelector.ImageGif>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Margin="20,10">
            <imagetools:AnimatedImage Source="{Binding src, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</local:ModuleTemplateSelector.ImageGif>
<local:ModuleTemplateSelector.ImageOther>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Margin="20,10">
            <Image Source="{Binding src}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</local:ModuleTemplateSelector.ImageOther>
```

One template is for gifs and the other one is for .jpg, .png etc.

I am getting the data in the ListBox using an API. So, sometimes there are more than two-three gifs besides the .jpg and .png, which cause the `OutOfMemoryException`. And I am sure the problem is somewhere in Imagetools itself.

So how should I avoid this exception? Are there any other ways to play gifs in a Windows Phone 8 app?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check what `DeviceStatus.ApplicationMemoryUsageLimit` returns and try monitoring your app memory usage with `DeviceStatus.ApplicationCurrentMemoryUsage` in runtime.

But I believe it is known ImageTools bug. To display images in Windows Phone **8** or **8.1** just use default `Image` control. It supports GIFs just fine.

EDIT:
Since Image control doesnt support animation in gifs I've done a quick search - you can either try this fix https://imagetools.codeplex.com/workitem/10396 for Image Tools:

In the constructor add..

```
this.Unloaded += new RoutedEventHandler(AnimatedImage_Unloaded);



void AnimatedImage_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Stop();
}
```

That will stop the timer and force the control to be unloaded when it is no longer in use.

Or you can try doing something similar as here http://advertboy.wordpress.com/2012/05/08/animated-gifs-in-xamlc/ and animate them yourself.

Comment: Memory usage is high when I play gifs using Imagetools. `Image` control doesn't play gifs. It shows them as normal images.

Comment: You are right. I've updated my answer, nothing new just quick search, you have probably come across those. I doubt I would be able to help you.